# Internet Connection Status using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to check if I'm connected to the internet using MATLAB? Is there a function that returns true if it's connected
to the internet?

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237718)

Comment: Specifically, see [Scott Burnside's solution using `java.net.URL`](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237718#605986).  Just point it to Google or something with faster response.

Comment: great, all the links are offline....

Comment: great, I can't upvote the guy stating the links are offline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar approach to the above:

```
function tf = haveInet()
  tf = false;
  try
    address = java.net.InetAddress.getByName('www.google.de')
    tf = true;
  end
end
```

It does have the benefit of not spawning an additional process and being independent from the fact, whether a particular site may at the moment be unavailable (which might be a good or bad feature).

Answer (score 5):

How about using a `ping` to one of Google's DNSes?

```
if ispc
    C = evalc('!ping -n 1 8.8.8.8');    
elseif isunix
    C = evalc('!ping -c 1 8.8.8.8');        
end
loss = regexp(C, '([0-9]*)%.*loss', 'tokens');
connected = ~isempty(loss) && str2double(loss{1}{1})==0;
```